# Guice multibinding-instances get different dependency-instances

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am pretty new to Guice and I am a little bit stuck at the moment.

I am developing the backend for a small game in Java. I want to dynamically inject the game's systems with Guice and I'm using multibinding for that:

```
private class InstanceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(GameInstance.class).to(GameInstanceImplementation.class);
        bind(EntityManager.class).to(EntityManagerImplementation.class);
        bind(EventBus.class).to(EventBusImplementation.class);
        bind(MessageBroker.class).toInstance(broker);

        Multibinder<GameSystem> systemBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), GameSystem.class);

        for (Class<? extends GameSystem> systemClass : systemsConfig) {
            systemBinder.addBinding().to(systemClass);
        }
    }
}
```

`systemsConfig` is just a List of Classes of `GameSystem`s I want the game to load.

In my `GameInstanceImplementation.class`, I inject the used `GameSystems` like this:

```
@Inject
public void setSystems(Set<IPMSystem> systems) {
    this.systems = systems;
}
```

And I get the GameInstance like this:

```
GameInstance instance = injector.getInstance(GameInstance.class);
```

I am doing it like this, because every `GameSystem` has different dependencies, some just need the `EntityManager`, some need the `EventBus` and so on.

Now it seems that every `GameSystem` has a different `EventBus`, EntityManager, etc... so they of course cannot communicate with each other.

I was expecting that every `GameSystem` gets the same instances of the bound dependencies.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance,
Froschfanatika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Guice creates a new instance of each dependency every time it's creating an object. If you want to change that behaviour, and get some dependencies shared between objects, then you need to put those dependencies into a different scope.

So, instead of...

```
bind(EventBus.class).to(EventBusImplementation.class);
```

you would do something like...

```
bind(EventBus.class).to(EventBusImplementation.class)
                    .in(Singleton.class);
```

then Guice will only every create a single instance of EventBus implementation, and anything which needs an EventBus as a dependency will be given that individual instance.

It's worth noting that Guice's behaviour in this respect is different from Spring's. Spring DI treats all beans as singletons by default. Guice default's is more akin to what Spring calls 'prototype' scope.

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. These Singletons aren't actual Singletons, right? If all references are deleted (including the injector), will they be garbage-collected?

Comment: Yeah, they're not singleton's in the sense of the GoF Singleton pattern. It's a scope which is specific to each Guice injector - only one instance exists per injector, so they get GC'd with the injector.